# Fitting Multiple Images on a web page that update from an API

Tags: javascript, html

I am Trying to Build a simple web page to display a feed from my cameras that pulls a still image from the camera via the cameras api and then regrabs the image with the API (so i can configure the frame rate of the cameras to cut down on mobile data)

I have managed to build a simple website with just one of the displays, but i want to be able to display all 8 of my cameras, IP addresses 192.168.0.157 - 165

My current code is

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var refreshInterval = 1000;
var url1 = "http://192.168.0.157/api/still?passwd=pass&"
var drawDate = true;
var img1;

function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.setAttribute("width", img.width)
        canvas.setAttribute("height", img.height)
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        if(drawDate) {
            var now = new Date();
            var text = now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
            var maxWidth = 100;
            var x = img.width-10-maxWidth;
            var y = img.height-10;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
            context.fillStyle = 'white';
            context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
        }
    };
    refresh();
}
function refresh()
{
    img.src = img.src = url1 + "t=" + new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout("refresh()",refreshInterval);
}

</script>
<title>Test4</title>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:init();">
<canvas id="canvas"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking make an array for every camera IP, and do all the API stuff for each of those.

```
    var ip = [
        "192.168.0.157",
        "192.168.0.158",
        "192.168.0.159",
        "192.168.0.160",
        "192.168.0.161",
        "192.168.0.162",
        "192.168.0.163",
        "192.168.0.164",
        "192.168.0.165"
    ];

    var img = [];

    function init() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        for (var i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
            img[i] = new Image();
            img[i].onload = (function() {
                canvas.setAttribute("width", img[i].width);
                canvas.setAttribute("height", img[i].height);
                context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                if (drawDate) {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var text = now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
                    var maxWidth = 100;
                    var x = img[i].width - 10 - maxWidth;
                    var y = img[i].height - 10;
                    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                    context.lineWidth = 2;
                    context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
                    context.fillStyle = 'white';
                    context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
                }
            })();
        }
        refresh();
    };

    function refresh() {
        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            img[i].src = "http://" + ip[i] + "/api/still?passwd=pass&t=" + new Date().getTime();
        }
        setTimeout("refresh()",refreshInterval);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help boris,

i have attempted to implement your code but am getting an error - 

    Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 
    'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type 
    '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or    
    HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or   
    OffscreenCanvas)'
    at Test2.html:21
    at init (Test2.html:34)
    at onload (Test2.html:48)

.